# Help for calculating the correct marked price?

Tags: finance

A) *For this equation I need help calculating the marked price.*

A retailer wants to make a **22% profit** on the sale of a television set. 
The television set cost the retailer **$560.**

**What should the marked price of the TV be?**

Silly enough as it is, I'm having a complete mind blank and can't seem to wrap my head around this question. Help would be great and a big thanks in advance!

***EDIT: Stupid me figured the second question out, turns out it was very simple and I was just over analyzing.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Say that the cost for the retailer is $C$ and that he makes a profit of $x$ %; that is to say that to  $1$  he pays, he adds $x$ percent. So, the sale price looks to be $$P=C \times (1+\frac{x}{100})$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks to you I was able to figure it out! Thank you.

Comment: You are very welcome !

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** for B): The discount is $\$220 \cdot 0.3$. And the new price is $\text{original price - discount}$.

Comment: Thanks, just as you helped I figured it out!

Comment: Nice, that you figured out yourself.